Introductory Texts on Measurable Groups and Haar Measure
I am very interested to know more about Measurable Group Theory and Haar measure, but I am unsure what books/notes/texts I should look for.
Here's my background: beginnings of measure theory and functional analysis, commutative algebra, some group theory, a sprinkle of algebraic topology and algebraic geometry, and willingness to learn :D
Unfortunately, I have not worked with manifolds and Lie groups/algebras, but if they are an absolute requirement to learn the topics I mentioned, so be it.
I am looking for a collection of texts that give a clear and concise introduction. What would your recommendations be? Thank you very much for your answers!
